# simple JQuery example is causing me troubles for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to JQuery and would like to try something. I just followed a simple tutorial to start up with on http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery
So I specified my script in the :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });                                   
</script>
```

and included a test link in the :

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

however, when I refresh thet document my browser keeps saying

```
TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

which I can understand for "normal" JavaScript but I believe this kind of function is new in JQuery. Can someone assist mer here, please?

links:http://wittmerperformance.com/site/

Comment: You are missing jQuery itself in your example. That code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Ys8f2/1/

Comment: jQuery actuaslly is embedded, I forgot to put the url there, edited my post now - check it out if you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you embed the jquery library?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Further more I think that currently "on" is state-of-the-art as in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue that you are facing could be that you haven't included JQuery library or it may be due to conflict, give it a try using

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("a").on('click', function() {
      alert("Hello world!");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(
    function() {

    $("a").click(
function(){
    alert("Hello world!");
    });

    });                                                                
    </script>
```

this is a working example.simpler. in your example you fotgot to close a function you started. count ( { } ) ; you are missing }) at the end. it shold work fine yours too.

full working example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(
    function() {

    $("a").click(
function(abc){
    alert("Hello world!");
    abc.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });

    });                                                                
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a>some link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no the OP has the correct number of opening and closing ({}). it's just not formatted as clearly as it could be.

Comment: i added the working script, thx for -1 :) and by the way, i forgot: i use return false, to cancel default action for href.

Comment: btw i didn't negate your answer and your answer still doesn't fix the question at hand. I suggest you go back and recount the opening and closing braces of the op's question as they are the same that you cut and pasted from their answer. The return false and prevent default are totally unnecessary.